# Unable to update redux state even after dispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am unable to update me redux store, The actions are dispatched as I can see the in the redux tools in chrome, however it returns a new handler object where the changes are reflected but the main store does not change, as a result the components are not getting updated values.
Below is a snippet of my code.

Attached redux js tools for chrome

Actual Store

```
export default function () {
    return{
        flowType : 'IAU',
        customerId : 'fasfa',
        actNumber : 'asfas'
      };
}
```

[image]

Combining All Reducers

```
import DataReducer from './DataReducer';
import Handler from './ReducerHandler'

const allReducers =Redux.combineReducers({
    appdata : DataReducer,
    handler : Handler
});


export default allReducers;
```

Rendered the form using.

```
import {setFlowType,setUserId,setServiceNumber} from './actions/Index';

let {createStore} = Redux
let {connect, Provider} = ReactRedux
const store = createStore(allReducers, window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__());

        ........
         ........
        `ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><UserInputForm/></Provider>,document.getElementById('UserInput'));`
```

Reducer

```
var initialState = {
        customerId : 'blablabla',
        actNumber : 'blabla'
      };

export default function(data=initialState,action) {  
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'ACCOUNT_NUMBER_CHANGED':
            return Object.assign({},data,{actNumber : action.actNumber});
        case 'USERID_CHANGED':
            return Object.assign({},data,{customerId : action.customerId});
    }
}
```

UserInputForm

```
var UserInputForm = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
    return (

    <div className="container-fluid">
    <div className="row">
    <div className="col-sm-3"></div>
    <div className="col-sm-8">
    <div className="row">
    <div className="form-group">
                                <div className="col-sm-4">
                                    <label htmlFor="UserId" >User Id</label>
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-sm-8">
                                    <input type="text" id="UserId" className="form-control" defaultValue={this.props.storeData.customerId} onChange={(event) => this.props.setUserId(event)}></input>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
<div className="row">
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <div className="col-sm-4">
                                    <label htmlFor='ServiceNumber'>serviceNumber</label>
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-sm-8">
                                    <input type="text" id="ServiceNumber" className="form-control" defaultValue={this.props.storeData.actNumber} onChange={(event) => this.props.setServiceNumber(event)}></input>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
<div className="col-sm-1"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            );
        }
});

    function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
        return bindActionCreators( {setUserId :setUserId , setServiceNumber:setServiceNumber}, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,matchDispatchToProps)(UserInputForm);
```

Action Creators

```
export const setUserId = function (event) {  
  return{
      type : types.USERID_CHANGED,
      customerId : event.target.value
  }
}

export const setServiceNumber = function (event) {  
  return{
      type : types.ACCOUNT_NUMBER_CHANGED,
      actNumber : event.target.value
  }
}
```

Comment: if the main store doesn't change then the reducers are not called properly.

Comment: what is the reducer function name? You don't have it.

Comment: I have a separate reducer file where it is exported as default.

Comment: Aha so you are having only one reducer in that file, that is default and you name it DataReducer later in the import `import DataReducer from './DataReducer';` ?

Answer (score 0):

You have written `matchDispatchToProps` instead of `mapDispatchToProps`. Also you haven't defined the `mapStateToProps` function that you are using in connect, do that and make the changes according to the props that you return from `mapStateToProps` in your code and it should work

```
var UserInputForm = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
    return (

    <div className="container-fluid">
    <div className="row">
    <div className="col-sm-3"></div>
    <div className="col-sm-8">
    <div className="row">
    <div className="form-group">
                                <div className="col-sm-4">
                                    <label htmlFor="UserId" >User Id</label>
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-sm-8">
                                    <input type="text" id="UserId" className="form-control" defaultValue={this.props.appData.customerId} onChange={(event) => this.props.setUserId(event)}></input>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
<div className="row">
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <div className="col-sm-4">
                                    <label htmlFor='ServiceNumber'>serviceNumber</label>
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-sm-8">
                                    <input type="text" id="ServiceNumber" className="form-control" defaultValue={this.props.appData.actNumber} onChange={(event) => this.props.setServiceNumber(event)}></input>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
<div className="col-sm-1"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            );
        }
});

  function mapStateToProps(state) {
     return {
         appData: state.appData,
         handlerData: state.handler

      }
  }
    function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
        return bindActionCreators( {setUserId :setUserId , setServiceNumber:setServiceNumber}, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(UserInputForm);
```

Comment: I have tried using `mapDispatchToProps` and there is a definition of `mapStateToProps` in my code here but it dosen't work , however I do get an action call in the redux debug tool. as attached.

Comment: Can you add your mapStateToProps function

Comment: Yes I have changed to mapStateToProps

Comment: I wanted you to add the definition of mapStateToProps in the question and console.log(state) in it to see if the state is available to you

Answer (score 0):

This issue was due to combine reducers block of code, as I had passed 2 copies of store into it

```
const allReducers =Redux.combineReducers({
    appdata : data,
    handler : Handler
});
```

Since there were two copes and Reducer was updating the changes to handler and other components were using appdata so the changes were not reflected. I fixed it by using

```
const allReducers =Redux.combineReducers({
    appdata : Handler
});
```